# Why does my web service show WSDL instead of svc?

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF web service running on HTTPS. When I compile and run it in Visual Studio 2008 and access the `Service.svc` file in browser, I expect to see the standard initial page beginning with:

> You have created a service.
>
> To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:

Instead, the service's WSDL file is shown. Is this some kind of a configuration error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post your service configuration and the skeleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WCF [HTML help page may have been disabled for HTTPS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedebugbehavior.httpshelppageenabled.aspx) in the [<serviceDebug>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788993.aspx) configuration section.

Look for something like this in your configuration file:

```
<serviceDebug httpsHelpPageEnabled="false" />
```